# Insert ID from one table to another in MySQL php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, one is `Information` and another is `work_force`

**Information**

[image]`

**work_force**

[image]

When the `addInformation()` get called, I want data insert into **Information**, and the `id` which is auto-increment will insert into table workForce, **column twf**.

This is what I've tried

**addInformation.php**

```
<?php 

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

        //Getting values
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $weather = $_POST['weather'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $status = $_POST['status'];
        $timeIn = $_POST['timeIn'];
        $timeOut = $_POST['timeOut'];

        //Creating an sql query
        $sql = "INSERT INTO information(name, weather, date, status, time_in, time_out) VALUES ('$name','$weather','$date', '$status', '$timeIn', '$timeOut')";
        $sql="INSERT INTO work_force (twf) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), )"


        //Importing our db connection script
        require_once('dbConnect.php');

        //Executing query to database
        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            echo 'Information Added Successfully';
        }else{
            echo 'Could Not Add Information';
        }

        //Closing the database 
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
?>
```

But I get stuck in insert `id` into `twf`.

```
 addInformation(name, weather, date2, status, first1[1], last1[1]);
 addWorkForce(Sub, NoP, NoH, a);

 public void addInformation(final String name, final String weather, final String date2, final String status, final String timeIn, final String timeOut) {
        class AddInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(WorkDetailsTable.this, "Please Wait", null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "AAAA"+s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //addWorkForce(Sub, NoP, NoH, Long.parseLong(s));
               // addWorkDetails(results, Long.parseLong(s));
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                data.put(Config.KEY_USER_NAME, name);
                data.put(Config.KEY_WEATHER, weather);
                data.put(Config.KEY_DATE, date2);
                data.put(Config.KEY_STATUS, status);
                data.put(Config.KEY_TIMEIN, timeIn);
                data.put(Config.KEY_TIMEOUT, timeOut);
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.ADD_INFORMATION, data);
                return result;
            }
        }

        AddInfo ru = new AddInfo();
        ru.execute(name, weather, date2, status, timeIn, timeOut);
    }
```

**addWorkForce.php**

```
<?php 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

        //Getting values
        $subcontractors = $_POST['subcontractors'];
        $noPeople = $_POST['noPeople'];
        $noHours = $_POST['noHours'];
        $twf = $_POST['twf'];


        //Creating an sql query
        $sql = "INSERT INTO work_force(subcontractors, number_of_person, number_of_hours, twf) VALUES ('$subcontractors','$noPeople','$noHours','$twf')";

        //Importing our db connection script
        require_once('dbConnect.php');

        //Executing query to database
        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            echo 'Work Force Added Successfully';
        }else{
            echo 'Could Not Add Work Force';
        }

        //Closing the database 
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
?>
```

Comment: you didn't execute the first sql, where do you execute?

Comment: Other than the extra comma in the second sql, you have to make sure that you run both of them, not just the second one that you overwrite the variable with.

Comment: @Jon checked my post again. Before that I add them seperately, however I cannot get the `id` inserted into 'twf'.....

Comment: @GoudaElalfy checked my post again. Before that I add them seperately, however I cannot get the id inserted into 'twf'.....

Comment: This comma `LAST_INSERT_ID(),` <<< right there, needs to be removed. Checking for errors on your query would have triggered a syntax error. Remove it and try again.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have two function addInformation(name, weather, date2, status, first1[1], last1[1]); and addWorkForce(Sub, NoP, NoH, a);, can share one php ?

Comment: then `$sql="INSERT INTO work_force (twf) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), )"` is missing a semi-colon at the end, and you're overwriting your first query above it. You need to either use a multi-query, or set 2 different variables for your queries.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I need to declare all the variables in addInformation.php as well?

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you check my php ?? Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34999370/only-the-list-which-has-the-max-id-can-be-deleted?noredirect=1#comment57726757_34999370

Comment: @John Please John, you shouldn't be asking for help here in comments about another question. I also have other things to do.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ok,I will remove them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some issues in your code ist of all last inserted id cant insert at like that without executing first query.

You can use like that:

```
//Creating an sql query
$sql = "INSERT INTO information(name, weather, date, status, time_in, time_out) VALUES ('$name','$weather','$date', '$status', '$timeIn', '$timeOut')";

//Importing our db connection script
require_once('dbConnect.php');

//Executing query to database
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    echo 'Information Added Successfully';
    $lastid = mysqli_insert_id();       
    $sql = "INSERT INTO work_force (subcontractors, number_of_person, number_of_hours, twf) VALUES ('$subcontractors','$noPeople','$noHours',$lastid)";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}else{
echo 'Could Not Add Information';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If `addWorkForce()` get called, will the data inserted into same row where `twf` inserted? Or it will insert into another row ?

Comment: yes it is.. now time is yours test it and dont forget my side note.. its more important for u. @JohnJoe

Comment: why did you undo my changing the mysql_ function to an mysqli_? http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34578045/2 that does not mix with mysqli_ and will fail.

Comment: hi @Fred-ii-: i didnt, my friend, i dont what is happening, on my server, some thing, answer updating not update...

Comment: @devpro they are already using `mysqli` in the question, the extra note wasn't needed. ^^

Comment: @Fred-ii-: i am really sorry, if i did, but i am receiving some issue on my server SO giving me captcha.. please update again my brother,

Comment: can you guys help me check whether my addWorkForce.php is correct? Should I remove the $twf in order to make the data get inserted into same line? Thanks

Comment: @JohnJoe: i have updated my answer along with your twf query.

Comment: @devpro But I have two function `addInformation(name, weather, date2, status, first1[1], last1[1]);` and 
 `addWorkForce(Sub, NoP, NoH, a);`, can share one php ?

Comment: @john-joe yes u can see my example

Comment: @devpro will the system know what are '$subcontractors','$noPeople','$noHours',$lastid` since they are not declared in php

Comment: U will define other three variables insertid already defined @john-joe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99601/discussion-between-devpro-and-john-joe).

Comment: This answer is not practicing secure querying.  Prepared statements with bound parameters should be employed.  For this reason, I cannot use this page to close new duplicates.  I refuse to promote insecure practices.